# Eliminating maven warrning: We have a duplicate

Tags: java, maven

In my **TestService** project I have following **pom.xml**:

```
<dependencies>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
   <artifactId>AnotherProject</artifactId>
   <version>${project.version}</version>
 </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                            <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                        </transformer>
                    </transformers>
                    <!-- exclude signed Manifests -->
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugins>
<build>
```

in my **AnotherProject pom.xml** have the same **maven-jar-plugin** and **maven-shade-plugin** configuration.

My questions:

1) Why I see warning such as:

> [WARNING] We have a duplicate org/apache/juli/logging/Log.class in
>   /home/xxx/.m2/repository/me/xxx/AnotherProject/1.0-SNAPSHOT/AnotherProject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

if I not include explicit this apache dependency in my **TestService**?

2) I was trying to eliminated these warns by using `<forceCreation>true</forceCreation>` in **jar plugin** and `<minimizeJar> true</minimizeJar>` in **shade plugin** in **TestService** by it doesnt give results. Am I doing something wrong? What is the proper way to do that?

3)
If is possible, how can I turn off all such [WARNING]? I dont want to use -q option during building.